# 一通のメールがMessageIDを複数持つ想定をすべきか

Tags: ruby, mail

メールを取得し、Message-IDをユニーク条件にしてDBに取り込もうとしたのですが

Mailクラスを確認すると `Mail::MessageIdsElement#message_ids` とMessageIDが複数あることを想定しているような記述になっていました。

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mail/2.5.3/Mail/MessageIdsElement

少し調べた限りでは一通のメールに一意のMessageIDが定まるようなのですが
一通のメールに複数のMessageIDが付加されている事は実際どの程度の頻度であることなのでしょうか？

具体的に知りたい点は配列を返す`Mail::MessageIdsElement#message_ids`ではなく、単一の文字列を返す`Mail::MessageIdsElement#message_id`を使って運用すると何か現実的に問題が発生する危険性はありますか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Message-Idが複数ついてる例は見たことないですが、それ以前の話として、同一のMessage-Idが別々のメールについてくることは割とあるので、一般的にはユニークであることは前提にしないほうがよいです。

Answer (score 3):

[RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6)によると Message-Id は最大1個なので実際に問題になることはないと思います。